How do you transition between two metal transition strips?
I am installing two 12' J-channel transition strips in aluminum (satin nickel). I have a 22' area so I need two strips. The strips are fine but I am looking for tips in hiding that I had to use two strips.
The product page shows almost exact example of what we are using.

Are you meaning to butt the ends together to make the length? How big is the face that will be seen when it is all in place? I can't imagine it being too big for the J channel I have seen and used... Is it an extrusion or bent to make the J shape?

@Jack - yes just concerned about two j channels butting against each other.    It is aluminum so cautious of a cut hazard

drywall j channel or siding j channel ?

@FreshCodemonger - added link

oh tile trim.  tile trim is thick enough that you should be able to get a near perfect join.  i'd probably run a diamond block to knock off any sharpness after cutting.

Gotta be careful about finish though.

Just do a butt join.
Make sure that the join is distant from other seams in the subfloor , and that the trim is well attached to it.

Probably not the best execution of a join technique but the idea is sound.  I've also had them leave the back projection long for an overlap.  You still end up with one edge that is going to be sharp / proud but I suppose this is better than potentially two edges.


If it is an extrusion, the joint will fit well together with no issue if the ends are well fastened. If it is a bent metal like Fresh Codemonger pictured, there is a way to cut the ends so the hemmed edge of the of the face edge will join together and stay aligned.
Codemonger is close, but the  part with the cut edge needs to go inside the the uncut piece, and the only cut on the needs to be on the top edge and the back flap left over from the top cut on the illustration, that will go into the hemmed edge and the lip of the hemmed edge will keep it aligned. That way when the cut one goes into the other, it has no choice but to tighten up on the bevel cut made.


it is a pretty solid material.   I have slight reservations about it being a cut hazard but I am really looking at making the vinyl installs I am doing look way better.   Getting rid of the huge vinyl trim is the first step and this is part of that.

Try this method on a scrap you have handy, you will see that they will line right up, with no more than the angle snip first and cutting the flap off that the angle snip made. You may be pleased for the way it goes together. But again the J channel for siding is made to cut with tin snips. Be sure to have the right and left hand snips, the red and green handles. If it was an extrusion, it needs to be cut with a saw.

Hire a seamless gutter company to come to your house and make a 22-foot piece.
I'm not encouraging this!  I like @Jack's idea best but if you want to up your game there it is.
What I actually suggest is you go to a shopping mall or an airport and see how they did it.  Probably nothing sophisticated.  Then ask yourself why you never noticed it before -- and apply that lesson.  In other words -- you are the only one who will ever notice this.  Don't overthink it.
